# MetaDataException: The type "*.CustomerEntity" has not been enhanced - whentrying to create row with Spring-JPA and OpenJPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, h2, openjpa

Full code is [on GitHub](https://github.com/dims12/TrySpringJpaPlusOpenJpa/tree/365c869302f71cfddf393300dce441aed99ffee8).

The main code is follows (entity and repository classes are omitted):

```
package org.inthemoon.tests.tryspringjpaplushibernate;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by Dims on 13.01.2017.
 */
public class Main {

   @Configuration
   @Import(Service.class)
   @EnableJpaRepositories("org.inthemoon.tests.tryspringjpaplushibernate")
   public static class _Config {

      @Bean
      File programDirectory() {
         File ans = new File(".");
         return ans;
      }

      @Bean
      BasicDataSource dataSource() {
         BasicDataSource ans = new BasicDataSource();
         ans.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
         File databasePath = new File(programDirectory(), "data\\tryspringjpaplushibernate");
         ans.setUrl("jdbc:h2:file:" + databasePath.getAbsolutePath());
         return ans;
      }

      @Bean
      public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
         LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ans =
            new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
         ans.setDataSource(dataSource());
         ans.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
         ans.setPackagesToScan(getClass().getPackage().getName());


         return ans;
      }

      @Bean
      public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
         OpenJpaVendorAdapter ans = new OpenJpaVendorAdapter();
         ans.setShowSql(false);
         ans.setGenerateDdl(true);
         ans.setDatabase(Database.H2);
         return ans;
      }

      @Bean
      public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
         JpaTransactionManager ans = new JpaTransactionManager();
         ans.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
         return ans;
      }

   }

   @Component
   public static class Service {

      private final CustomerRepo customerRepo;

      @Autowired
      public Service(CustomerRepo customerRepo) {
         this.customerRepo = customerRepo;
      }

      public void doSomeOperation() {

         CustomerEntity customer = new CustomerEntity();
         customer.setId(1);
         customer.setNam("New Customer");

         customerRepo.deleteAll();

         customerRepo.save(customer);

      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(_Config.class);

      Service service = context.getBean( Service.class );
      service.doSomeOperation();

   }
}
```

When trying to initialize context, an exception occurs saying

> Error creating bean with name 'customerRepo': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property
>   'mappingContext'

with root cause of

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.4.2-r422266:1777108 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.MetaDataException: The type "class org.inthemoon.tests.tryspringjpaplushibernate.CustomerEntity" has not been enhanced.
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.ClassMetaData.resolveMeta(ClassMetaData.java:1834)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.ClassMetaData.resolve(ClassMetaData.java:1808)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processBuffer(MetaDataRepository.java:829)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolveMeta(MetaDataRepository.java:726)
    ...
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with enhancement in OpenJPA?  This exception would simply seem to be telling us that the entity has not been enhanced.  There could be a bigger issue here, but I'm hopeful you've simply not enhanced your entities.  If you are in a JSE environment you can simply give the runtime a -javaagent and point to the openjpa jars.  Take a look at the enhancement topic in the OpenJPA docs for info on a -javaagent or other types of enhancement:

http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.2/apache-openjpa/docs/manual#ref_guide_pc_enhance

Thanks,

Heath Thomann

Comment: Of course I didn't do any enhancements, both because I didn't know about it and alse because I don't wan't to. I think they should do everything automatically :)